# Implicit conversion of a method to Func<T, Tresult>

Tags: c#, delegates, extension-methods

I have a an extension class that extends `Func<T, TResult>` whose signature looks like this:

```
public static ITryAndReturnValue<TResult> Try<T, TResult>(this Func<T, TResult> func, T arg, int retries)
```

I can implement it on a method by casting the method to `Func<T, TResult>` like so...

```
Func<string, string> func  = request.DownloadString;
string response = func.Try(urlA, 3);
```

But what I really want to do is this:

```
string response = request.DownloadString.Try(urlA, 3);
```

But I get this compile time error.

> CS0119 'WebClient.DownloadString(string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Is there anything I can do to get my extension method to work like I want it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't call an extension method on a method group or on an anonymous function.

Section 7.6.5.2 of the C# specification requires that:

> An implicit identity, reference or boxing conversion exists from *expr* to the type of the first parameter of M<sub>j</sub>.

(Where *expr* is the expression you're trying to call the extension method on, and M<sub>j</sub> is the extension method itself.)

A *method group conversion* (the conversion which allows you to write `Func<string, string> func  = request.DownloadString;`) is *not* an identity, reference or boxing conversion. It's a separate kind of conversion (section 6.6 of the spec).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I can do to get my extension method to work like I want it to?

No.

Extension methods were explicitly designed to *not* work on method groups.

Comment: The regular static method invocation syntax works for me with the example given - possibly due to the better betterness in C# 6?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! :) I don't understand what you mean when you say it won't work in the "regular" way. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Bummer. I wish I had the better betterness.

Comment: @yozepi: Eric means that you could *try* to call it as `string response = ExtensionContainingClass.Try(request.DownloadString, urlA, 3);` - but he predicts it won't work. I reckon it might, depending on which version of VS you're using, and potentially what the type of `request` is.

Comment: Oh, I completely missed that `T` can be inferred there.  Yes, this should work. I'll remove the erroneous paragraph.